# Reflexive pronoun (myself) grammar issue

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage, reflexives

I was writing in MS Word 2003, and it put a green underline under the word *myself*, as used below.

> Don’t trust people, even ***myself***, trust the code.

I ran the spell and grammar check, but it completed without any errors or suggestions.

If I change the sentence by adding "you should" after the comma, the problem goes away.

> Don’t trust people, even myself, ***you should*** trust the code.

But that is not the preferred phrasing. What, if any, problems exist?

p.s.   The closest I could find to this issue is [Microsoft word and confusion about himself/he/him](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/203067/microsoft-word-and-confusion-about-himself-he-him), but it does not help explain why I am right or wrong.

Comment: Quoting from the very question you linked to: "This is a good example of why you should turn off the so-called 'grammar checker' on MSWord". There is absolutely no reason or excuse for anyone to use it. It does not know the first thing about English grammar. Conversely, you had a firm grasp of English grammar long before you even knew the words "grammar" or "Microsoft" existed. This tool should be your slave, not the other way round. Why use it against your own best judgment? It just wasted a considerable chunk of your precious lifetime with this question alone. It eats your life away.

Comment: *Don’t trust people, even myself **;** trust the code.* -- Do all problems go away now? Let us know. (Check your grammar.)

Comment: @RegDwigнt: I dunno. This might be one of those occasions where dumb software actually got it right. Since I would say *"Don't trust **me**"* rather than *"Don't trust **myself**"* (as an imperative with implied subject "You"), it seems to me it would be more correct to say *"Don’t trust people, even **me**"*.

Comment: The commas are at best highly confusing, at worst enough to make the sentence complete gibberish. After reading the sentence four times, I still had no idea what you were trying to say.

Comment: Can anything that reports suspected sentence fragments with the phrase, "Fragment, consider revising" be trusted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd agree with @RegDwigнt in that you should just write what you feel is the best way to say what you intend. That said, it's probably picking up on the fact that you say *myself* without referencing *I*. In theory, it wants you to write, "Don't trust people, even *me*, trust the code."

As a sidenote: 
You have two separate clauses there: "don't trust people" and "trust the code". Rather than using the comma to separate them, personally I'd use a semicolon.

> Don't trust people, even me/myself; trust the code.

Edit: I see the comments beat me to the semicolon lol.

Comment: yes the semicolon does "fix" the issue.

Comment: This makes sense, it turns out if I right click the word, it suggests "I" as a replacement.

Comment: I will use "Don’t trust people, even me; trust the code."

Answer (score 3):

Using that reflexive pronoun is incorrect. The implied subject (as FumbleFingers's comment says) in the imperative clause `Don't trust people` is in the 2nd person `you`, so for an object pronoun you should prefer using the non-reflexive version **me**:

> Don’t trust people, even **me**, trust the code.

You'd use the reflexive pronoun when referring to the subject:

> Don’t trust people, even **yourself**, trust the code.

---

Curiously trying it out in MS Word underlines both *myself* and *yourself*. I guess we can't have everything

Comment: This is a very good explanation on the reflexive pronoun issue.

Comment: I took it as emphatic _myself_, rather than reflexive _myself_. But I think _me_ is better.

Comment: @JasonPyeron Not really! See Colin's note comment.

Comment: @Araucaria There's not enough context to make it emphatic. True, it *could* be interpreted that way, but (to me at least) it looks a lot more like an erroneous reflexive